# How to rewrite multiple text files contents to lists in same file?

Tags: python, text, global

I have multiple text files which contain two to three lines of text. I need to rewrite these file in order to have lists in them to make data structured. I do not find the way how solve it with multiple files automating the task.

```
import sys
import glob

path = '*.txt'   
files = glob.glob(path)

contents = []   
for name in files:
     with open(name) as f:
       lines = f.read().splitlines()
       contents.append(lines)
```

Text before:

```
Announcement
45 789 answers
Rules obliged
```

Text after rewriting:

```
Announcement, 45 789 answers,Rules obliged
```

## Final Working code

```
import glob

   path = '*.txt'   
   files = glob.glob(path)

   contents = []   

   for name in files:
         # no change made to your reading code
         with open(name) as f:
           lines = f.read().splitlines()
         # overwrite the original files, put the text in one line, separated by 
         #comma+space
         with open(name,"w") as f:
         f.write(", ".join(lines))
         f.write("\n")  # add optional linefeed for the sole line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overwrite your files with a joined version of the file lines:

```
for name in files:
     # no change made to your reading code
     with open(name) as f:
       lines = f.read().splitlines()
     # overwrite the original files, put the text in one line, separated by comma+space
     with open(name,"w") as f:
       f.write(", ".join(lines))
       f.write("\n")  # add optional linefeed for the sole line
```

note that it yields:

```
Announcement, 45 789 answers, Rules obliged
```

not

```
Announcement, 45 789 answers,Rules obliged
```

also note that if any problem occurs when writing back the file (disk full, python syntax error, keyboard interrupt...), the original file is destroyed. To play it safe, you could write in a different name, and move the file when OK:

```
     with open(name+".bak","w") as f:
       f.write(", ".join(lines))
       f.write("\n")  # add optional linefeed for the sole line
     shutil.move(name+".bak",name)
```

as both files are on the same filesystem, there's no performance issue (delete+rename)

Comment: Thank you! I have tested first code and it has done the job.